# Parse Error Handling swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, swift3

In Parse Documentation we can find this Session Error Handling in Swift.

```
// Swift
class ParseErrorHandlingController {
  class func handleParseError(error: NSError) {
    if error.domain != PFParseErrorDomain {
      return
    }

    switch (error.code) {
    case kPFErrorInvalidSessionToken:
      handleInvalidSessionTokenError()

    ... // Other Parse API Errors that you want to explicitly handle.
  }

  private class func handleInvalidSessionTokenError() {

  }
}

// In all API requests, call the global error handler, e.g.
let query = PFQuery(className: "Object")
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
  if error == nil {
    // Query Succeeded - continue your app logic here.
  } else {
    // Query Failed - handle an error.
    ParseErrorHandlingController.handleParseError(error)
  }
}
```

Can someone help me make it to swift 3?

Till now I have done the following

```
import Foundation
import Parse

class ParseErrorHandlingController {
    class func handleParseError(error: NSError) {
        if error.domain != PFParseErrorDomain {
            return
        }

        switch (error.code) {
        case PFErrorCode.errorInvalidSessionToken.rawValue:
            handleInvalidSessionTokenError() //error here again.

             // Other Parse API Errors that you want to explicitly handle.
        }


    }
    func handleInvalidSessionTokenError() {
        PFUser.logOutInBackground { (error) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                likesOfArray.removeAll()

            }

        }

    }
```

And i call the function with the following code.

```
ParseErrorHandlingController.handleParseError(error: error as! NSError)
```

But i get the following error

```
Missing argument for parameter #1 in call
```

I'm really stucked !

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you declared `handleInvalidSessionTokenError()` inside your other function, in the Parse's example it's a private class function. About the error you could try to use case `PFErrorCode.errorInvalidSessionToken.rawValue` instead.

Comment: Your suggestion about the `PFErrorCode.errorInvalidSessionToken.rawValue` worked! But now i get another error. Could you check out the updated question?

Comment: Ok no worries i figgured it out <3 !!